# c program.Issue with adding record into text file

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having some problem with adding new records in a sequential access file. When user enters the model code, the program is supposed to check for it and display that an entry with the same name already exists if a duplicate had been found. When I run my code, it just shows:

```
Record already exists
Record already exists
Record already exists
Record already exists
```

when:
1.the code exists in the file
2.the code does not exist in the file.

Can someone help me with this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//function to add record
void stockEntry(){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("stock.txt","a+");

    //fopen opens file.Exit program if unable to create file
    if(fp==NULL){
        puts("File could not be opened");
    }//ends if

    //obtains information from user
    else{        
        printf("\nEnter model code,model name,cost,price and quantity(Use space to separate inputs)\n");
        scanf("%s %s %f %f %d",code,a.name,&a.cost,&a.price,&a.quantity);

        rewind (fp);
        do{
            if(strcmp(code,a.code)!=0){      
                //write details into stock.txt
                fprintf(fp,"%s %s %.2f %.2f %d\n",a.code,a.name,a.cost,a.price,a.quantity);
            }
            else{
                printf("Record already exists\n");
            }

        }while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %f %f %d\n",a.code,a.name,&a.cost,&a.price,&a.quantity)==5);
    }
    //fclose closes file
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Where are `code` and `a` declared/initialised and what are their types?

Comment: code is declared before main body

Comment: a is name of the struct array and initialised before main body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `do...while` loop, which will compare the data before
anything has been read from the file; first time through, you're
comparing to an old value of `a.code`. Also, you're writing data in the
middle of the file, and I see no guarantee that all records are the same
length.

Also, you're using `a` to hold both the data you got from the user, and
the data read from the file. You want two structures, one for each
purpose.

I'm not sure why it always gives you `Record already exists`, but a loop
like this should give you the results you want. (I didn't compile or
test it, this is just off the top of my head.)

```
int exists;
struct ... curr;
...
scanf("%s %s %f %f %d", curr.code, curr.name, &(curr.cost),
      &(curr.price), &(curr.quantity));

exists = 0;
rewind(fp);

while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %f %f %d\n",
       a.code, a.name, &(a.cost), &(a.price), &(a.quantity)) == 5) {
    if (strcmp(curr.code, a.code) == 0) {
        printf("Record already exists\n");
        exists = 1;
        break;
    }
}

/* At this point, either exists == 1, in which case we're at an unknown
   point in the file and wish to do nothing, or exists == 0, in which
   case we're at the end of the file and wish to write a new record. */

if (exists)
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %.2f %.2f %d\n",
            curr.code, curr.name, curr.cost, curr.price, curr.quantity);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. I notice you don't have the `Informed` badge. You can earn that by [taking the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), which explains a lot about how to use the site.